# Change element class without using css animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have a class with the following type of css animaton

```
.cssanimation {
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out
    -o-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out
    transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out
    .. some other changes in position
}
```

I have the div

```
<div id="thediv"> ... </div>

$('#thediv').addClass('cssanimation') //animates the object
```

I do use this animation at some point but sometimes I'd like to add it without invoking the animation

Does Jquery have a way in which I can add classes without invoking their css animations?

Comment: what is the reason to add a CSS class with animation if you don't want to use it? Create another that fit your needs

Comment: Id like to use it later, but at the rendering stage when I create the content with jquery I wouldnt like to see it

Comment: You're asking, essentially, 'can I add a class without using parts of that class?' and the answer is, of course, 'no.' Use a second/different class.

Comment: Why don't you just add the class _when_ you want to animate it?

Comment: Aren't the changes in position supposed to be set using @keyframes? or do you mean transitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you create another class without animation and use it.

It's not difficult to change CSS rules at runtime, but apparently it is difficult to find the rule you want. PPK has a quick tour of this on [www.quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean CSS Transitions. For http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/animations, you can define keyframes to fine tune a transition, but I don't think you need it.

The following code does what you need, I think. http://jsfiddle.net/Y69VB/1/

**HTML**

```
<button id='anim'>animate</button>
<button id='move'>move</button>
<div id='moveme' class='pos1'>Here</div>
```

​
**CSS**

```
.cssanimation {
    transition: top 2s;
    -moz-transition: top 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: top 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: top 2s; /* Opera */
}

#moveme {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.pos1 {
    top: 30px;
}

.pos2 {
   top: 80px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $moveme = $('#moveme');

function togglePosition() {
    $moveme.toggleClass('pos1');
    $moveme.toggleClass('pos2');
}

$('#anim').click(function(){
    $moveme.addClass("cssanimation");
    togglePosition();
});

$('#move').click(function(){
    $moveme.removeClass("cssanimation");
    togglePosition();
});
```

​
    ​

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#thediv').detach().addClass('cssanimation').appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R5mQC/3/